# Sum values of variables?

Tags: prolog

I'm new with Prolog, and I'm trying to create a predicate that find a specific fact and sum the values.

This is my predicate:

```
position(X,T,P1,P2,P3,P4) :- object(X,C1,C2,C3,C4,T1),
                 T>T1,
                 move(X,S1,S2,S3,S4,T2),
                 T2>T1,
                 T2=<T,
                 P1 is C1+S1,P2 is C2+S2,P3 is C3+S3,P4 is C4+S4.
```

And what i get is this:

```
    ?- position(car0,31,P1,P2,P3,P4).
    P1 = 930,
    P2 = 278,
    P3 = 1057,
    P4 = 365 ;
    P1 = 943,
    P2 = 288,
    P3 = 1058,
    P4 = 370 ;
    false.
```

I want the sum of all(S1,S2,S3,S4) values of move with the (C1,C2,C3,C4) of object but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Hint: how would you sum up a list of values?

Comment: What is `move/6` doing here btw?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is a movement of an object, where X is the name of object,T2 the timestamp, and the other is the shift. So, object represent the initial coordinates, move represents of how much the object has moved.

Comment: It looks as if you here actually have already made a sum up of `(S1, S2, ...)` and `(C1, C2, ...)`.

Comment: then you probably should include first a `position(X, T, P1, P2, P3, P4) :- object(X, P1, P2, P3, P4), T > T1.`, and then thus use the above predicate to generate more results.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes but, the value that i want have to be a sum of all the move fact, i mean starting from the initial coordinates of object:
(947,297,1075,388)
The two results that i get are the some of the previous coordinates with:
(-17,-19,-18,-23),
(-4,-9,-17,-18),
But what i want is a unique value, i mean:
(947,297,1075,388) + (-17,-19,-18,-23) + (-4,-9,-17,-18)
That should be:
(926,269,1040,347)

Comment: ah, you mean the *cummulative* sum?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to do too much in a single predicate. It usually is better to split the logic in several predicates that each perform a certain task.

## Cummulative coordinates

We can first create a list of list of values with [**`findall/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3):

```
all_moves(X, T, Diffs) :-
    findall([T1, C1, C2, C3, C4], (move(X,C1,C2,C3,C4,T1), T1 <= T), Cs),
    sort(Cs, Diffs).
```

We here thus sort the `move/6`s on timestamp, and create a list of 5-tuples with `[T1, C1, C2, C3, C4]` with `T1` the time stamp, and `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, and `C4` the timestamps.

Next we can define a cummulative sum function by making use of [**`plus/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=plus/3) and [**`maplist/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3):

```
cumsum(P, _, P).
cumsum(P, [[_|D]|R], P2) :-
    maplist(plus, P, D, P1),
    cumsum(P1, R, P2).
```

then we can thus obtain the positions of an object with:

```
position(X,T,P1,P2,P3,P4) :-
    object(X, C1, C2, C3, C4, T1),
    T > T1,
    all_moves(X, T, Mvs),
    cumsum([C1, C2, C3, C4], Mvs, [P1, P2, P3, P4]).
```

## Final coordinates

If we only need the final coordinates, we can improve the above. In that case, the order of the moves is irrelevant, as long as these are properly filtered. So we can define `allmoves_unsorted/3`, like:

```
all_moves_unsorted(X, T, Diffs) :-
    findall([C1, C2, C3, C4], (move(X, C1, C2, C3, C4, T1), T1 <= T), Diffs).
```

Then we can sum these up with the `object`, with [**`foldl/4`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4):

```
final_position(X, T, S1, S2, S3, S4) :-
    object(X, P1, P2, P3, P4, T1),
    T1 < T,
    all_moves_unsorted(X, T, Diffs),
    foldl(maplist(plus), Diffs, [P1, P2, P3, P4], [S1, S2, S3, S4]).
```

Comment: It works, but i have a question. Is possible to have only the final coordinates?
Given the result:
ᘀ?- position(car0,31,P1,P2,P3,P4).
P1 = 947,
P2 = 297,
P3 = 1075,
P4 = 388 ;
P1 = 930,
P2 = 278,
P3 = 1057,
P4 = 365 ;
P1 = 926,
P2 = 269,
P3 = 1040,
P4 = 347 ;
false.
Would be better to have only:
P1 = 926,
P2 = 269,
P3 = 1040,
P4 = 347

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with the foldl functions since final_position is giving me false, while the all_moves_unsorted gives the list of the moves

Comment: @Jt1995: no, it was in the call with `object(X, C1, C2, C3, C4, T1),` (was `object(X, T1, C1, C2, C3, C4)`), which makes no sense.

Comment: cf. `findall(X, ( X=2;X=2;X=1 ), Y), sort(Y,YS), setof(X, ( X=2;X=2;X=1 ), YS).` ...

Comment: @WillNess: there is a small difference: `setof/3` will fail if it can *never* satisfy the goal. whereas `findall/3` and `sort/3` will yield an empty list.

Comment: more importantly though, sums of [2,2,1] and [1,2] are not the same. :)

Comment: @WillNess: but since we timestamp the list, it will not filter out unique values, unless of course there are two `move` facts with the same timestamp for the same object (with the same delta), but then I would assume that these two should not be add up?, since then a `move/6` with the two values is likely a mistake.